# How to use git diff to return a 0 if a specific folder in the working copy is the same as the repository and a 1 if they are different

Tags: git, shell, unix

Basically I have trying to write a unix script comparing the repo to the working copy that I have.  I want to run certain tests if 1 or more certain files are different, but not have them run if some random file in the repo is changed.  How could I do this?

Comment: Note that a Git repository is a collection of commits. Every commit in the repository is a complete (stand-alone) collection of all the files, as if in a tarball or zip archive, as of the time of that commit, plus the metadata that goes with that commit. So it makes no sense to compare a *repository* to a *working tree*, as a working tree is a collection of files, not a collection of commits.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could pull it off with some tricks. Assuming the remote is called `origin`:

```
git fetch origin # get the latest from the remote repo
rev1=$( git rev-parse origin/some-branch:some-dir )
rev2=$( git rev-parse HEAD:some-dir )
if [ "$rev1" == "$rev2" ]; then
    echo no need to continue because they are exactly the same
    exit 0
fi
echo there is a difference
exit 1
```

Now that I think about it, this will work when comparing *not* with the working tree but with the last revision..... if you *really* need to do it against the working tree:

```
git fetch origin
lines=$( git diff --name-only origin/some-branch -- some-dir | wc -l )
if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
    # no change
    echo No changes
    exit 0
fi
echo there is at least a change
exit 1
```